# Wrong sql syntax to get data from other table

Tags: java, mysql

I'm having, trouble getting data from some other table.
I'm using Java preparedStatements and mySQL.

This is my sql query:

```
String sql = "SELECT alumno.nombre, alumno.apellido, curso.nombre, aula.numero FROM "+
                "((alumno INNER JOIN curso ON alumno.id_curso = curso.id_curso) "+
                "INNER JOIN aula ON alumno.id_aula = aula.id_aula) "+
                "WHERE (alumno.nombre=? "+
                "OR alumno.apellido=?) "+
                "OR curso.nombre=? "+
                "OR aula.numero=?;";
```

I'm getting this error: `Error :Column 'curso' not found.`. Why is it trying to get a column when I'm using the dot(.) notation to access the `curso` table. I'm new to Java-mySQL.

This is my java code:

```
try{
       conn = Conexion.connect();
       stm = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
       stm.setString(1, "Diego");
       stm.setString(2, "Rios");
       stm.setString(3, "Informatica");
       stm.setString(4, "202");
       rs = stm.executeQuery();
       System.out.println(stm);
       while(rs.next()){
           String nombre =  rs.getString("nombre");
           String apellido =  rs.getString("apellido");
           String curso =  rs.getString("curso");
           String aula =  rs.getString("aula");

           System.out.println(nombre);
           System.out.println(apellido);
           System.out.println(curso);
           System.out.println(aula);

           a.setNombre(nombre);
           a.setApellido(apellido);
           a.setCurso(curso);
           a.setAula(aula);

           lista.add(a);
       }
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error :"+e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if(stm != null){
            try {
                stm.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(AlumnoDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        if(conn != null){
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(AlumnoDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

PS: It is working in mySQL-workbench.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't see how that query could generate that error, assuming the `?` are replaced as SQL parameters.

Comment: try to use some alias, like `curso as c` then use it in where like `c.nombre`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, they are replaced.

Comment: @LKTN.25 I'll try that

Comment: include the code you set the parameters in the preparedstatement.

Comment: @LKTN.25 i'll do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend writing the query as:

```
SELECT a.nombre, a.apellido, c.nombre, au.numero
FROM alumno a INNER JOIN
     curso c
     ON a.id_curso = c.id_curso INNER JOIN
     aula au
     ON a.id_aula = au.id_aula
WHERE a.nombre = ? OR
      a.apellido = ? OR
      c.nombre = ? OR
      au.numero = ?
```

However, I don't see how the use of aliases, removing the parentheses, or removing the semicolon could result in the error you see.  One possibility would be an invalid character in the `SELECT` or `WHERE` clauses, one that is not visible.

EDIT:

I think your problem is this code:

```
String curso =  rs.getString("curso");
```

There is no output column called `curso`.  This can be fixed in the `select`:

```
SELECT a.nombre, a.apellido, c.nombre as curso_nombre, au.numero
```

Then use:

```
String curso =  rs.getString("curso_nombre");
```

Comment: @DiegoRios . . . I suspect that there is other code apart from this query being run.

Answer (score 1):

the culprit is here,

```
       String curso =  rs.getString("curso"); // You should retrieve here a column and not a table.
       String aula =  rs.getString("aula");
```

Thats why you get an error `Error :Column 'curso' not found.`.

you should put the column you write on your query like:

```
String curso =  rs.getString("curso.nombre");
String aula =  rs.getString("aula.numero");
```

Comment: @Gordon Linoff answered it 4 mins before you. But thank you anyway! I upvoted your answer.

Comment: it's ok as long as we can help.